# iOS 11 PDFKit - curl transition

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, ios11

With iOS 11, PDFKit has been made available in iOS. It has the capability of use a UIPageViewController but not to set the transition style ( [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview/configurations/book_display) ).

**Is there any way do change the transition style of the PageViewController of PDFView from the default to page curl?**

Answer (score 4):

I've gone through the view hierarchy of a PDFView and it seems like underneath it is using UIPageViewController. However, setting the transition style to curl is not possible as the property can only be set during initialization.

One workaround I tried, though inefficient when loading PDFs with large number of pages is to create your own UIPageViewController and set its view controllers on the datasource to view controllers each containing a PDFView whose page are set to the corresponding index.

```
let pageCount = self.pdfDocument!.pageCount - 1
for index in 0...pageCount {
  let page: PDFPage = self.pdfDocument!.page(at: index)!
  let pdfView: PDFView = PDFView(frame: self.view.frame)
  pdfView.document = self.pdfDocument
  pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
  pdfView.go(to: page)
  pdfView.autoScales = true
  let vc = UIViewController()
  vc.view = aView
  pages.append(vc)
}
```

Again this is a work around and perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, I had come to your same conclusions, the problem is (as you said) that  it's an inefficient solution to create a PDFView for each page (and it's not his job to display only a page). I also saw that Apple had a sample project that displays PDF with curl page transition, but it was made before PDFKit and it is really buggy ( https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html ).

Comment: use a quicklook framework to previewing the documents including to read the .pdf files also.. https://www.appcoda.com/quick-look-framework/

Comment: @HariNarayanan I don’t want the file only to be displayed, I need PDFKit for interaction

Comment: If you are willing to use a commercial solution, https://github.com/PSPDFKit/PDFXKit - a drop-in replacement for Apple PDFKit using the industry leading PSPDFKit framework, offers fast page curl.